# How to group by different columns and find the percentage based on one column?

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I want to group the following data table by `var1` and `var2` and then find the percentage in `var2`:

```
data <- as.data.table(list(var1 = c("x1","x1","x2","x1","x2"), 
                           var2 = c("y1","y1","y1","y2","y2"))) 

data[, .(count = .N), by=.(var1, var2)]

#    var1 var2 count
#1:   x1   y1     2
#2:   x2   y1     1
#3:   x1   y2     1
#4:   x2   y2     1
```

This is the outcome that I am interested in:

```
#    var1 var2 count  ratio in var2
#1:   x1   y1     2         0.66
#2:   x2   y1     1         0.33
#3:   x1   y2     1         0.5
#4:   x2   y2     1         0.5
```

How to change the code to achieve this?

Comment: data[, .N, by=.(var1, var2)][, ratio:=N/sum(N), by=var1]

Comment: It looks like you know enough about data.table to solve this problem on your own. Did you give it a try?

Comment: I don't know why I missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
data <- data[, .N, by = .(var1, var2)][, ratio:=N/sum(N), by = var2]
```

which results in:

```
> data
   var1 var2 N     ratio
1:   x1   y1 2 0.6666667
2:   x2   y1 1 0.3333333
3:   x1   y2 1 0.5000000
4:   x2   y2 1 0.5000000
```

Comment: This does not create a new column in `data`, btw, since you have a `][` before you reach the `:=`. There's `data[, rat := {bigN=.N; copy(.SD)[, x := .N/bigN, by=var2]$x}, by=var1]`, but it doesn't seem like a good way.

Comment: Also `data %>% group_by(var2, var1) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(n / sum(n))`